# Consolidating javascript switch statement for ajax function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've got a form with sections to add data to my database via a modal window and then dynamically add the data to the relevant select elements in the form via ajax. It works great for the first modal window, but not the others.

I know why this is happening. It's because the js I wrote is using a switch statement to get the value of a hidden input but the hidden input does not have a unique name attribute. What I'm trying to accomplish is consolidate the code for the ajax call to one function, but the way I am carrying it out is obviously not going to work.

Is there a better way to do this? Should I just have 5 different ajax calls instead?

Sample of modal window html with form (there are 5 of these, each different e.g. supplier, manufacturer, model, etc):

```
<!-- Add New Supplier Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="supplierModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="supplierModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="supplierModalLabel">Add new asset supplier</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" class="modal-submit" autocomplete="off" action="{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'supplier']) }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="supplier">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputModelNew">Supplier name *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputSupplierNew" id="inputSupplierNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter supplier name" required="required">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Add New Supplier Modal -->

<!-- Add New Manufacturer Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="manufacturerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="manufacturerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="manufacturerModalLabel">Add new asset manufacturer</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" class="modal-submit" autocomplete="off" action="{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'manufacturer']) }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="manufacturer">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <label for="inputManufacturerNew">Manufacturer name *</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="inputManufacturerNew" id="inputManufacturerNew" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter manufacturer name" required="required" data-error="Enter a manufacturer name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="backend-error"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Add New Manufacturer Modal -->
```

My ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.modal-submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit action

        $(".backend-error").html(''); //clear out previous error messages
        $('input').removeClass('input-error'); //clear error border class

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var type = $('input[name="type"]').val();

        switch(type){
            case "supplier":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'supplier']) }}';
                var modalName = '#supplierModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputSupplierNew';
                break;
            case "manufacturer":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'manufacturer']) }}';
                var modalName = '#manufacturerModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputManufacturerNew';
                break;
            case "model":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'model']) }}';
                var modalName = '#modelModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputModelNew';
                break;
            case "status":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'status']) }}';
                var modalName = '#statusModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputStatusNew';
                break;
            case "category":
                var url = '{{ action('AddAssetController@addDescriptor', ['type' => 'category']) }}';
                var modalName = '#categoryModal';
                var modalInput = '#inputCategoryNew';
                break;
        }

        $.ajax({
           url:url,
           method:'POST',
           data:data,
           success:function(response){
                refreshData(newId = response.id); // set newId to the id of the newly inserted item
                $(modalName).modal('hide'); //hide modal
                $(modalInput).val(''); //clear input value
           },
           error:function(e){
                //console.log(error.responseJSON.error)
                //console.warn(error.responseJSON.error);
                console.log(type);
                $.each(e.responseJSON.error, function (i, error) {
                    $(modalInput).addClass('input-error');
                    $(modalName + ' .backend-error').html(error[0]); //return error from backend
                });
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of `var type = $('input[name="type"]').val();` use `var type = $(this).find('input[name="type"]').val();` (also note that you can easily replace that entire switch statement with three similar statements to determine url, modalName and modalInput)

Comment: Well that was easier to fix than expected. Thank you. I don't understand what you mean by replacing the switch statement. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For instance you can use `const url = $(this).getAttribute('action');` and `const $modal = $(this).closest('.modal');` then `$modal.modal('hide');`

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to js in this capacity. I've never seen the const function. Read up on it and I see it is used for a value that will never change. I'm just not sure how to implement it here. When I try, it breaks functionality of the script.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, it's `const url = $(this).attr('action');`. The third one is `const $modalInput = $(this).find('.form-row input');`, then `$modalInput.val('');`

Comment: I'm closer. Only thing I'm stuck on is populating the modalName var which is the id of the modal window. I've tried ```$('.modal').val($(this).attr("id"));``` but it's returning an object not the id.

Comment: ```var modalName = '#' + type + 'Modal';``` - close enough I guess.

Comment: You don't need the `id` in the first place, just store the modal and input as jQuery elements and you can simply call their methods without having to select them again.